# With border-box on a text input with a given height, padding and border, inspector gives wrong height?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

`http://jsfiddle.net/a9u5h0s7/`

code:

```
#example{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

if you look at that jsfiddle (i tried in chrome) and inspect the input element, you'll see it is supposed to have a height of 30px, however, if you do content+padding+border, you get 25px...

main question here is:
is this a bug in chrome detecting the content's size or is it actually rendering 20px for the content while it should be 25?

Comment: I have always 30px. So it works perfectly :).
Border-box means that padding and border will be part of inputs height.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is nice topic

```
 #example{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black; 
   }
```

is correct in all browser where, #example element size is 30px in that 20px is element height, 4px padding top size, 4px padding bottom size, 1px is padding top and 1px is padding bottom so 20+4+4+1+1 = 30